# Terminating indicator for binary byte array in Golang?

Tags: go, binary, arrays

In Golang if I have a byte array of binary data how do I determine the termination of actual data if it is in a larger array.  For example if I do the following, reading a file when it is plain text:

```
    chunk := make([]byte, 1024)
..read some data into the chunk but only 10 bytes are filled from the file...
```

I can then determine the actual size of the data by doing the following:

```
n := bytes.IndexByte(chunk, 0)
```

When it is plain text n will give me the end of the actual data - how do I do that if the data is binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[io.Reader's](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) Read function returns the number of bytes read.

You can then create a sub-slice of that size.
For example:

```
data := make([]byte,1024)
n, err := reader.Read(arr)
if err != nil {
    // do something with error
} else {
    rightSized := data[:n] 
    // rightSized is []byte of N length now and shares the underlying 
    // backing array so it's both space and time efficient
    // this will contain whatever was read from the reader
}
```

Comment: Thank you David! I noticed that on the file .Read after os.Open I get the number of bytes read too, regardless of the size of my byte array - this set me off looking at that in further detail so thank you.

Comment: Yes, most byte readable things have that same signature of "func Read([]byte) (int, error)".  So you use the same code for reading files, sockets, umm... other stuff that gives you bytes (drawing a blank)...